# ASP.NET MVC Script Bundle Takes Too Long To Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am out of ideas on this one. An MVC site we developed takes too long to load. The Network tool shows it takes over seconds to load the JavaScript! It is in a bundle and being minimized. I can't figure out why this bundle could take so long. Any ideas?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/site").Include(
                         "~/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/jquery-migrate-{version}.js"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/json2.js"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/knockout-{version}.js"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/jquery.unobtrusive*"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/jquery.validate*"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/jquery-ui*"
                       , "~/Scripts/lib/jquery.lockSubmit*"
                       , "~/images/jquery.js"
                       , "~/images/script.js"
                        ));
```

Here is the Network Tab of the Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of network tab

Comment: Is this on initial load of the site or after the application has been spun up? Meaning, you have hit a few pages already and the app pool isn't going through its start up process

Comment: No this is on Startup

Comment: Is the site on local network, dev machine or hosting?

Comment: local network to try to find problem

Comment: you can see size of generated file, it's too big. for quick fix you can try split this bundle

Comment: are you sure that you need two `jquery` files `"~/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"` and `"~/images/jquery.js"`?

Comment: Yes, I asked that. the images/jquery is from the client and they did some things.

Comment: i mean that load this js file take long time, because this file is too big, try split it to few bundle files

Comment: You probably don't need all these scripts on the first page of your application. Most likely, for example, jquery validation is not needed. You can split the bundle, and use them on different pages as required.

Comment: What happens if you turn off bundling? is it much quicker?

Comment: Did you turn IIS compression on? It shouldn't be some 600-700kb after gzip.

Comment: I noticed you are using asterisks. I guess these are wildcards. Are you sure you're aren't including both the minimized *and* regular versions?

Comment: Having squinted at the screenshot I figured out the URL, and tested it myself. The bundle is minified, however it is not compressed (GZIPped) accounting for the large size. Using fiddler, I can see that the large time gap is between the "GotResponseHeaders" and "ServerDoneResponse" - maybe a bandwidth issue?

Comment: How do you compress (GZip) the bundle?

Comment: @JonathanWood: Bundling takes care of that. During release mode, it includes only min files and during debug mode, it includes the expanded files.

Comment: @user2471435, you need to enable dynamic compression. It requires the component in IIS to be installed - you can find out more here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/urlcompression

Answer (score 1):

Looking by your network tab screen grab, you have bundled a lot of files together and the size is **0.63 MB** which is too big a size for minimized js files.

One thing you could do is split your js files into seperate bundles. Also could u share the actual size of the js files you are using, I find it very strange that the files you mentioned after minimized is still too big.